# Updating one cell in MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

**Explination**:

I will attempt to illustrate my problem. (Wanna skip it? Jump down to "Here is my problem")
Here a MySQL table similar to mine.

```
| NAME | PASSWORD | FOLLOWING 
| Johny | XieofEnfoEQ | NULL 
| Isabel | nfOEnfoiJEJj | NULL
```

I am attempting to create a php code that will allow the users to follow other users. The system follows the following steps:

1) Connect to Database.

2) Fetch the imploded array of the people the current user is following (imploded arrays are essentially arrays turned into strings

3) Explode that string back into an array

4) Add the requested user

5) Re-Implode the array back into a string

6) Update the "FOLLOWING" cell for the current user to the new imploded string

7) Send the requested user an email saying that they have a new follower

**Here is my problem**:
Say I'm logged in as Johny. When I attempt to follow Isabel (for example), it gives me no errors, and Isabel gets the email. However, when I check the database, the FOLLOWING cell is still NULL. How do I fix this? My entire code is below with important values removed.

**CODE**:

```
<?php
// ensure that they are logged in
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
require_once "Mail.php";
if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin()) {
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("http://####BLANKED####/HomeworkBox/Signup/login.php");
    exit;
}

$searched="search";

// check the URL to fetch variables
if (isset($_GET['search'])) { // fetch what to send back to the search
    $searched = $_GET['search'];

}

if (isset($_GET['follow'])) { // fetch who to follow
    $follow = $_GET['follow'];

}

else {
    header('Location: http://####BLANKED####/engine/search.php?search='.$searched);
    die;
}

$member = $fgmembersite->UserFullName();

// check if this is a valid 
$username="####BLANKED####";
$password="####BLANKED####";
$database="####BLANKED####";
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password)or die();
@mysql_select_db($database)or die();
$id = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE `name` = '$follow'");
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

}

else {
    header('Location: http://####BLANKED####/engine/search.php?search='.$searched);
    die;
}

$follow_data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$follow_email = $follow_data[3];

$id = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE `name` = '$member'");
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

}

else {
    header('Location: http://####BLANKED####/engine/search.php?search='.$searched);
    die;
}

$member_data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$member_email = $member_data[3];
$member_following = $member_data[14];

$following_list = explode(',', $member_following);
$following_list[] = $member;
$member_following = implode(",", $following_list);

$member_refined = str_replace(' ', '%20', $member);

mysql_query("UPDATE members SET following=$member_following WHERE email='$member_email'");

$from = '<####BLANKED####>';
$to = $follow_email;
$subject = "You Have a New Follower!";
$body = "Hello ".$follow."\r\n\r\n".
    "".$member." has added you on ####BLANKED####! \r\n".
    "You can add them back by clicking the following link. \r\n\r\n".
    "http://####BLANKED####/engine/follow.php?follow=".$member_refined." \r\n\r\n".
    "(If the link looks odd, DO NOT CLICK IT! We are not responsable for \r\n".
    "any damage caused to you, your device, or anything else!) \r\n\r\n".
    "Regards,\r\n".
    "####BLANKED####\r\n\r\n";

$headers = array(
                 'From' => $from,
                 'To' => $to,
                 'Subject' => $subject
                 );

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
                                    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                                    'port' => '465',
                                    'auth' => true,
                                    'username' => '####BLANKED####',
                                    'password' => '####BLANKED####'
                                    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} 

header('Location: http://####BLANKED####/engine/search.php?search='.$searched);
die;
?>
```

Comment: Putting arrays into the database like this is horrible design. Use a relation table, where each follower is a different row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the string in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET following='$member_following' WHERE email='$member_email'") or die (mysql_error());
```

If you checked for errors from `mysql_query` (as I've shown), you would have seen this error.

You also need to escape your data to protect against SQL injection. It would be better if you converted to PDO or mysqli and used parametrized queries.

Comment: I will attempt to swap to mysqli. Could you explain what exactly a PDO is however? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As others found out, you've missing the quote for $member_following

It's recommended to add some error detection like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($your_sql);
if ( !$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

By the way, keeping following members like this is NOT good for data consistency.e.g. When a member is deleted, you might have to scan every other members to clean up the $member_following field, otherwise that field could have deleted members.

A normalised way to do it would be having a member_follow_member table for this MANY-TO-MANY relationship. I can see, you are working with MySQL at very low level ( i.e. not using ORM or even PDO ), it will really be a pain to do it.  Mixing PHP with HTML/Javascript is another bad practice.

Comment: Could you recommend a better method for doing this?